# How to pass argument to a script in vim system() call?

Tags: system, vim

I would like to pass current filename `%` as argument of the shell script in `system()` call :

```
let rev=system("~/script %")
```

How can I do that for real ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `exec`:

```
exec 'call system("~/script " . expand("%"))'
```

Depending on what you want to do you might not need `exec` at all (like `:h system()` suggests):

```
let foo = system("~/script " . expand("%"))
```

Comment: Ok, but how can I "feed" the variable `rev` then ?

Comment: @sputnick: I just edited my answer with the usage of a variable for the system call's output. The `exec` is usually only needed if you want to interact with Ex commands.

Comment: -1 for not using `shellescape()`. If you pass arbitrary arguments to a shell command you should always use it.

Answer (score 1):

Playing around with `expand()` (thanks kongo2002) :

```
let script="~/script " . expand("%")
let rev=system(script)
```

Works as a charm =)

Comment: You should be using `shellescape()` here. For the same reason you should not use `!~/script %`: `%` will pass filename unescaped.